Support beam cut away for French Drain
We just realized the contractor cut one of the vertical support beams to install a french drain around the basement perimeter. The french drain is in and they have no plan to be able to reinstall that beam.
Help! What do we do? How do we get that support beam back into place?

Photographs would be helpful.

Not sure what you are seeing without pictures.  If you think the support is important, get the building inspector or a structural engineer in to check, then you get the contractor to repair/replace it at his cost.

A vertical support member is usually a "column" or "post."  A beam is typically a horizontal support member.
